# How can I load my glTF file on SceneViewer with ARCore Android SDK

Tags: android, arcore, gltf, sceneview

I'm following the document at Google (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/scene-viewer#ar-only).

I put glTF file in `assets/models` directory (as same location with `Andy.obj`)

and I tried to load glTF 2.0 file (from [KhronosGroup Sample](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models)) but failed:

```java
    Intent sceneViewerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri intentUri =
            Uri.parse("https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.0").buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("file", "models/BoxTextured.glb")
                    .appendQueryParameter("mode", "ar_preferred")
                    .appendQueryParameter("title", "Untitled")
                    .build();
    sceneViewerIntent.setData(intentUri);
    sceneViewerIntent.setPackage("com.google.ar.core");
    startActivity(sceneViewerIntent);
```

In document (which linked above), there is no clue how to write the code to load glTF from local.

what can I do for resolved this problem in android?

Thanks.

edit: The source is based on https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java, and I worked `HelloArActivity.java`, ARCore Android SDK version is 1.17.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself.

Set path for glTF to absolute path (like "/sdcard/BoxTextured.glb", not "models/BoxTextured.glb")

I think it can not find (also no convert) relative path from that function.

You have to get a path by `//assets/~` or something if you want to use relative path.

EDIT:

also, there is `Environment` class which has method `getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`. i might be solved above problem.

Comment: instead of assets, do you know if it is possible to load files from the public Downloads folder ? I want to be able to download models and show them in SceneViewer.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere you can do in Uri.parse(Model_URL) your Model_URL is your glb files

Comment: Hi! I tried your solution but i alwas get an error with "Failed to Load Gltf url '/storage/emulated/0/FILENAME.glb' reason: /storage/emulated/0/FILENAME.glb". I recostruct my file path like this Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/IlBattente_17_glb_mesh_20.glb"), and use it like this .appendQueryParameter("file", Uri.parse(modelUrl).toString)

Comment: This also doesn't work for me, even after requesting external storage read permission. SceneViewer can't find the file for some reason.